# Django get model field

Tags: python, django

I am trying to select a user_id base on the user that was selected and then pass the user_id to another function to perform some calculation for the selected user when a form entry is saved. But I am not sure how to accomplish that. When a new entry is added and save (add_monthly_entitlement) and the form is saved, I want to pass the selected user_id to another method to perform some calculation.

[image: Image of the form]

```html
 class month_and_year(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Month = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="", null=True)
        Year = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.first_name



@login_required()
def add_monthly_entitlement(request):
    if request.POST:
        entitlement_form = update_entitlement_form(request.POST)
        my_field = month_and_year._meta.get_field('user_id')

        if entitlement_form.is_valid():
            calculate_monthly_entitlement(my_field)
            entitlement_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/staff_balances')
    else:
        entitlement_form = update_entitlement_form
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = entitlement_form
    return render(request, 'update_entitlement_form.html', args)


def calculate_monthly_entitlement(get_id):
    get_id = get_id
    get_leave_balance_id = Leave_Balance.objects.get(user_id=get_id)
    get_entitlement_id = monthly_entitlement.objects.get(user_id=get_id)
    get_leave_balance_id.Leave_current_balance = get_leave_balance_id.Leave_current_balance + get_entitlement_id.entitlement
    get_leave_balance_id.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can use session variables

# set session value
request.session['user_id'] = value

# get session value
request.session['user_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by getting the selected field value and passing the value to the function that performs the calculation.

form.cleaned_data[fieldname]

hopes this can help someone in the future

```html
def update_monthly_entitlement(request):
    if request.POST:
        entitlement_form = update_entitlement_form(request.POST)
        if entitlement_form.is_valid():
            my_field = entitlement_form.cleaned_data['user']
            calculate_monthly_entitlement(my_field)
            entitlement_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/staff_balances')
    else:
        entitlement_form = update_entitlement_form
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = entitlement_form
    return render(request, 'update_entitlement_form.html', args)
```